# Multiple optional command parameters with discord.py

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command

I was looking at asking for multiple optional parameters with discord.py, although I'm not sure how to do it. This is my example, although I'm pretty sure it's wrong.

````
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot
    @commands.cooldown(rate = 1, per = .75, type = commands.BucketType.user)
    #@bot.command.cooldown(1, 10, commands.BucketType.default)
    @bot.command(name = "search", alises = ['find')
    async def ecommand(ctx, limit, *tags, *args):
        print('Testing API')```


I'd like to to receive input where it checks for args, but not all of them are needed to function.. example: Command can receive e!search 10 cat or e!search 10 fav_count cat and still work. 

For further note, I'm taking these args and using them in a API search, so I need a way of getting the information from each arg, rather then just putting it all as one. Maybe there is another way to do this tho, I am just unsure. 

Thank you for the help :)
````

Answer (score 1):

Some tiny mistake you should fix before continuing :

-aliases was misspelled.

-missing the close bracket "}" for aliases.

-the first argument of the function "ecommand" should be "self" instead of "ctx" since you are doing it inside of a class.

### Set a default value for the argument

```
    @bot.command(name = "search", aliases = ['find'])
    async def search_command(self,ctx,limit,*,args=None):
        if args == None: 
            await ctx.send("Enter a something to search !")

        #Turn it into a list
        arg_list = args.split()

        #Your Searching code
```

By doing this, you set the default value of the argument to `None`. So
that it does not cause an error and break the whole script when the user enter nothing to search.

Comment: I think that's a pretty good idea, I was confused about the, * , arugs=None at first, sense I need the ability for multiple words within, but if I can format the command around something like a comma, then possibly I can use this. I Know what I wrote wouldn't have worked but I needed an idea for how to compose it :) Thank you!